# What is the proof that anti-derivative gives function = area under curve?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

For many years now I have thought about this but have not been able to get a clear answer. We all know that $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ gives us a function we call as the derivative that gives the gradient of the function at $x$. To get the anti-derivative, we can use the $\int$ of the derivative and get back the original $f(x)$.

This part of $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ has been explained to me many times since high school and is crystal clear. By using this I obtain that derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$ and derivative of $x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}$. What has never been explained to me is the proof that $\int$ of a function in fact gives the area under $f(x)$ and that also using the Riemann sum. I have always wondered about this and have not been able to get the answer. What is the proof of this?

Comment: please don't try to prove anything using f(x)=x since that is not a good example. I need a proof here for continuos functions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Comment: @quantum231 I think the problem here is that you want to prove the riemann sums or the integral are equal to the area below graph. But the thing is, the *area below the graph* is just an intuitive non mathematical concept.You can't talk about it mathematically, therefore you can't prove the integral will give the area below the graph. If what I just said doesn't apply to you, then how do you define *area below the graph*?

Comment: Let $s(t)$ be the area under $f(x) |_{[0,t]}$, consider $\frac{1}{h}(s(t+h)-s(t))$ as $h\to 0$.

Comment: @GitGud I'm not sure I would say the area below the graph is non-mathematical. Signed area under the graph of a function seems like a perfectly well-founded geometric idea. I always thought of Riemann integrability as a definition for the signed area under a curve.

Comment: @rschwieb "Riemann integrability as a definition for the signed area under a curve" - I have no problem with this. As for the validity of area below the graph as a geometric concept, how do you define signed area under the graph? All is good when it's rectangles only, otherwise I really don't see how to go about it.

Comment: @GitGud Yeah, I think we agree mostly. I just thought saying that it was non-mathematical was not good :)

Comment: @quantum231 : any calculus book will have a proof.  They will probably first prove that the derivative of $\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ with respect to $x$ is $f(x)$, if $f$ is continuous.  That is not too difficult.  From there it is very easy to prove what you are looking for.  Do you have a calculus book?  Look for the "Fundamental Theorem of Calculus".  If you don't have a calculus book, you can probably find proof in Wikipedia or elsewhere if you Google it.

Comment: I still don't understand why the mystery behind this idea is not cleared neither at the High School nor at the University when the idea of how derivative works out is clearly explained using limit of h.

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, assume that $f(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.
Riemann sums give the *sum* of areas of certain pairwise disjoint rectangles (overlapping boundary lines don't count), which by any reasonable concept of area is the area of the *union* of these rectangle. And if we can give a meaning to "area under the curve" then this area is "obviously" between the Riemann lower sums (which describe areas of subsets of the area under the curve) and Riemann upper sums (same with supersets). If the function $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[1,b]$ (which just says that lower and upper Riemann sums converge to a fixed number $c$ as the corresponding partitions become finer and finer (the rectangles become thinner and thinner), then we say $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx=c$ and as this integral is between all lower and upper Riemann sums, the same number $c$ must be what we call area under the curve.

If you consider $F(x):=\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$ for a continuous function $f$, then you will note that $F(x+h)-F(x)=\int_x^{x+h}f(t)\,\mathrm dt$ can be estimated by a simple Riemann sum with a single rectangle. The lower sum is a rectangle of width $h$ and heght $\min\{ f(t)\mid x\le t\le x+h\}$ and the upper Riemann sum is the same with $\max$. Therefore the difference quotient
$\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}h$ is a number between the min and max of $f$ on $[x,x+h]$. As $h$ becomes smaller, both min and max converge to $f(x)$ if - as we required - $f$ is continuous. In other words, the derivative of $F$ is $f$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a mathematician nor a calculus practitioner; nor is this a proof. But this is how I've come to terms with anti-derivative being the area under the derivative curve. I don't even know if this is the right way to think about it, but here it is:

Let's say I'm given a function, f(x), which I'm told is the derivative of some unknown function F(x). My task, should I choose to accept it, is to construct the function F(x). I'm additionally given the value of F(k), at some k, as a starting point. These are the only two things I'm given—I don't know how F(x) looks, for example.

Conveniently, let's assume that f(x) is a constant positive function. What this is telling me is that, whatever F(x) represents, it's gaining magnitude at a constant rate as it moves to the right. Also, for convenience, let's picture a discrete version of the derivative:

The discrete derivative function, f(x):

```
 |
 |
 |-.-.-.-.-.-.
 | | | | | | |
```

The derivative, f(x), encodes changes to its anti-derivative, F(x). Given a starting value for F(x) at k, I can (re-)construct the anti-derivative by taking discrete steps to the right, and then copying the *previous value* across and additionally stacking up the change incurred on top of it. Obviously, the previous value carries with it all the differences before it.

The construction of anti-derivative, F(x), starting at some k:

```
   |
   |
   |          o
   |        o |     Incrementally stacking up changes ("differences")
   |      o | |     up until any given point, to construct the anti-derivative.
   |    o | | |
   | .o.-.-.-.-     ---
   | ??????????      ^
   | ??????????     F(k)
   | ----------      v

 ->| k |<-
```

Writing these out:

```
F(k + 0) = given
F(k + 1) = F(k) + f(k + 0)
F(k + 2) = F(k) + f(k + 0) + f(k + 1)
F(k + 3) = F(k) + f(k + 0) + f(k + 1) + f(k + 2)
```

Thus:

```
F(k + ni) = F(k) + sum of every f(k + i) for all 0 <= i < n
          = F(k) + Area under a segment of the derivative function.
```

What this is telling me is that the anti-derivative function only gives the appearance of a real function. Under the hood, at any given point, it's only a "dummy function" accumulating all the differences (obtained by consulting the derivative) until that given point.

Come to think of it: the derivative function itself might be an anti-derivative of some other function, meaning f(x) is also a dummy function taking orders from somewhere else. So it's turtles all the way down.